# NSFetchResultController, combination of fetchLimit & returnsObjectsAsFaults for pagination

Tags: swift, core-data

I am using a `NSFetchResultsController` and I am trying to get pagination to work. I came across those two properties on a `NSFetchRequest` and I highlighted the part I have a question about on:

`fetchLimit` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506622-fetchlimit)):

> For every object store except the SQL store, a fetch request executed
>   with a fetch limit in effect simply **performs an unlimited fetch and**
>   **throws away the unasked for rows**.

`returnsObjectsAsFaults` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506756-returnsobjectsasfaults)):

> These faults are managed objects, but all of their property data
>   resides in the row cache until the fault is fired. When the fault is
>   fired, Core Data retrieves the data from the row cache.

Is it appropriate to combine those two properties? Setting a `fetchLimit` and set `returnsObjectsAsFaults` to true?

When settings a `fetchLimit`, `CoreData` does still query everything for every row. When using `NSFetchResultController`, I am configuring `UITableViewCells` based on the objects from `CoreData`, thus I think the objects shouldn't return as a fault. But if I combine both properties, I am afraid CoreData is querying every row for the predicate without a limit and querying the whole object (not a fault), based on the docs.

I have a doubt if I should use both properties. Does anyone has any experience with large datasets combined with `NSFetchResultController` with pagination? I don't really know how to debug this.

Comment: Did you find out any solution for this? I end up not using NSFetchedResultsController.

Answer (score 0):

With the use of NSPredicate and fetchLimits and fetchOffsets it can be done.

```
CDAppDelegate * delegate = (CDAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext * context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
for(int i = 0; i < 34;i++){
    CDObject * object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CDObject"
                                                      inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [object setValue:i];
}
[delegate saveContext];

NSFetchRequest* request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CDObject"
                               inManagedObjectContext:context]];

 NSError* error = nil;

 NSUInteger count = [context countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];
 assert(error == nil);

 NSLog(@"Total count: %u", count);

 request.fetchOffset = 0;    
 request.fetchLimit = 30;

 NSLog(@"Fetch offset: %u, limit: %u", request.fetchOffset, request.fetchLimit);

 NSArray* page1 = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
 assert(error == nil);

 NSLog(@"Page 1 count: %u", page1.count);

 request.fetchOffset = 30;    
 request.fetchLimit = 30;

 NSLog(@"Fetch offset: %u, limit: %u", request.fetchOffset, request.fetchLimit);

 NSArray* page2 = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
 assert(error == nil);

 NSLog(@"Page 2 count: %u", page2.count);

[request release];
```

Comment: 1. This does not answer my question and 2. the programming language is different than Swift (see tag)